# NextJS 13.0 Firebase-admin refresh token

Tags: firebase, next.js, middleware, next.js13, firebase-admin

In NextJS, I setup a middleware where it checks the session saved in cookie, and basically validates it, how do I refresh the token if after verifying the token has expired? I am using firebase-admin when verifying token

I tried implementing firebase client and try to get the user then call the `getIdToken()` function but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: "I tried implementing firebase client and try to get the user then call the getIdToken() function but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly." Can you share your code, because it is from the client that you should refresh the token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.